# How to make a .bmp file (some hex data) display as a qr-code

Tags: encoding, qr-code, decoding, bmp

I am a college student dealing with some file problems.

I have saved a .bmp file which I knew it should be a qr-code.

Instead, it displayed as a meaningless picture.

[Example meaningless picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAKke.png)

I'm wondering what's might be happening and what can I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Huh. First, welcome to SO.

Second, your question needs clarification. How do you get this file (maybe it's auto-generated or something)? Can you ask for another one and see if it's meaningless too?
File definetely looks corrupted, but I'm not sure if it's due to creation error or some kind of saving/network/whatever malfunction.

Also, your question is possibly off-topic and you ought to address it to https://superuser.com/ instead.